# Implicit conversion from child class to abstract child class with the same base

Tags: c++, casting, abstract-class, derived-class

Is it possible to implicitly cast derived class to abstract derived with common base without needing to cast to base first?

Example:

```
class IOBase
{
public:
    virtual std::vector<unsigned char> read(int size) = 0;
    virtual void write(const std::vector<unsigned char> & data) = 0;
};

// Derived abstract class
class Input : public IOBase
{
private:
    using IOBase::write;
};

// File IO derived class
class FileIO : public IOBase
{...}

class FileInput : public FileIO
{
private:
    using FileIO::write;
};


void ReadFromInput(Input& input) {...}

void main()
{
    FileInput fi;
    ReadFromInput(fi); <-- compiler error, 
                           should be first casted to base class IOBase and
                           then to abstract class Input

    FileIO f;
    ReadFromInput(f); <-- compiler error
}
```

Note that `read` and `write` methods could not be const.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FileIO` does not derive from `Input`, so not only can the cast not be omitted, but the cast is in fact not even *allowed*, because there *is* no `Input` subobject anywhere in your complete object `fi`.

It seems like you may have need with a virtual base class:

```
class Input : public virtual IOBase { /* ... */ };
class FileIO : public virtual IOBase { /* ... */ };

class FileInput : public Input, public FileIO { /* ... */ };
```

Then no cast would be required in your call.

Comment: Ok I see, I forgot that i have to derive from Input class. How about FileIO to Input class conversion, is it possible to implicit cast between them? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @keroxavi22: Not implicitly (obviously, that would be terrifying). You can cast up to the base and down to the other derived class *if* you really are talking about two separate subobjects of the same most-derived object. You may need a dynamic cast to cast down from a virtual (= dynamic) base.